# specifying the value of "n"

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

If two coins are tossed $5$ times, then the probability of getting $5$ heads and $5$ tails is – but I got stuck in one step –

**My approach:** Since it seems overly similiar to binomial question so I am gonna go with that

$p$-probability of getting head on tossing a coin is 
 $x=\text{number of times getting head}$

But what should I fill in $n$-number of trials... $5$ or $10$ and can u explain the reason?

Comment: your question's a bit vague, but if the coin is tossed 5 times, then getting **5 Heads** is one outcome with equal probabilty to the possibility of getting **5 Tails**, which is a another outcome of this experiment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your experiment correctly:

I guess you have five turns and in each turn you throw two coins simultaneously. Your desired outcome is:

1. Turn: (head,tail)
2. Turn: (head,tail)
3. Turn: (head,tail)
4. Turn: (head,tail)
5. Turn: (head,tail)

I am not sure if you differ between the coins. Does it make a difference which coins shows which sign? In other words is

1. Turn: (tail,head)
2. Turn: (head,tail)
3. Turn: (head,tail)
4. Turn: (head,tail)
5. Turn: (head,tail)

the same result or a different? the first component refers to the first coin and respectively for the second.

I guess it is the same. So your probability to achieve (head,tail) in one turn is $p=\frac{1}{2}$ and since you have five turns you have $n=5$. By plugging that into the formula you obtain
$$\binom{5}{5}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{5-5} = \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^5$$

Comment: all the experiments are independent

Comment: this method is more understandable....in my book they solved using 10 trials so i got confused

Comment: I am still not sure if your text book states the same experiment. However, if it does you can do it like I did.

Comment: also one more thing ,the answer given is 63/256 in this case so maybe what you were assuming was right and if it comes the way it is,will u inform me the update

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: I think the  two outcomes  you wrote on your body are not same  same so I think your assumption about them being same is wrong  and also the answer coming was 63/256,this is what i was saying

Comment: this would just change the value of $p$ to $\frac{1}{4}$. I think you should read the exercise again and try to figure out what the real task is. Alternative you could post the exercise in the exact wording.